# Getting process id via EnumWindows... Can someone please explain me why this code is working?

Tags: c, windows-10, codeblocks

I'm trying to get handles of windows. Then I was trying to get associated process id for every handle. But somehow, I'm magically get process_id out of nowhere. Please guide me here.

If I try to initialize process_id using GetWindowThreadProcessId() function, I encounter a runtime error.
However, if I comment out that part of code and let process_id print in both printf() functions, the programs runs successfully, displays data and exits cleanly. It should be garbage value here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

WNDENUMPROC DisplayData(HWND str, LPARAM p) {
    LPDWORD process_id;
    DWORD P_ID;
    printf("PID :: %x\n", process_id);

    //this is where error occurs
    //P_ID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(str, process_id);

    printf("Found: %x, P_ID: %x\n", str, process_id);
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    EnumWindows( (WNDENUMPROC) DisplayData, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*displays data* which is random, garbage, undefined behaviour strikes again.

Comment: Have this "*`//P_ID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(str, pid);`*" uncommented would not compile.

Comment: sorry, that's because P_ID is uninitialized. It is of type DWORD. So please define this before compiling. I'll make same change to given code also.

Comment: also, I changed pid to process_id in error line.

Comment: @alk Thanks, I got the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LPDWORD target = (LPDWORD) 0;  // Replace 0 with PID of the task from taskmgr.
HWND target_handle = NULL;  // stores the handle of the target process

WNDENUMPROC DisplayData(HWND str, LPARAM p) {
    LPDWORD thread_id;
    DWORD process_id;
    char title[30];

    GetWindowTextA(str, (LPSTR) &title, 29);
    process_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(str, (PDWORD) &thread_id);

    if( thread_id == target & IsWindowVisible(str) ) {
        // Target thread with associated handle
        // printf("Handle Addr: %lu, Thread ID: %lu, Process ID: %lu, Title: %s\n", str, thread_id, process_id, title );
        target_handle = str;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    EnumWindows( (WNDENUMPROC) DisplayData, 1);

    ShowWindow(target_handle, SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(1000);
    ShowWindow(target_handle, SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}
```

The Thread ID shown by this code is the one that is displayed in Task Manager as PID. target_handle variable contains handle address after the execution of EnumWindows() function, just as required.